# Find + zgrep covers only last 3 days

Tags: bash, grep, find, zgrep

I'm having a problem with `find` and `zgrep` commands. Here's the full command I try to use:

```
find ~/xyz/server*/p* -mtime -14 -type f | xargs zgrep -h "qq/ww/ee/calendar\|qq/ww/ee/flights"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is `zgrep` (as the files are in .gz) a pattern `qq/ww/ee/calendar` or `qq/ww/ee/flights` from directory `~/xyz/server1/p*` and `~/xyz/server2/p*` (file names begin with p) that were modified/created within last 14 days.

The problem I'm having is that despite the fact that the above `find` command works flawlessly if used alone, when I add `xargs zgrep` to it it only gives me results from last 3 days.

Before you ask - yes, the files are there. And please bear in mind that I'm rather new to this world.

Comment: Can you give us the output for the `find` command and then the output for the full command you are using?

Comment: Perhaps something which shows us the modification times of these files too

Comment: Maybe none of the older files match the pattern

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Case solved. I wasn't notified that the log structure has changed recently and URL path is a bit different for these older files. Oh well, at least I've learned something new. Thanks guys, and thanks for sites recommendations.